# MacBook Pro- retinal display, OSX 10.11.1- Can dual boot OSX 10.5.8?

Tags: multi-boot

Have new 2015 MacBook Pro, running ElCapitan, any chance I can partition and run old OSX 10.5.8? Or create Virtual Machine to run it?
Several Graphics apps not upgradable to El Capitan. Have received conflicting info on this from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

With very few exceptions [right on the cusp of a new model & OS release] you cannot boot any Mac into an OS older than itself.
There are no drivers in existence for that machine under 10.5.8

There is also no license for virtualisation of any non-server OS below 10.7 & many issues with even the server version of 10.5.8 - received wisdom would be that you can get OS X Server 10.5.5 to virtualise, but no higher, on both VM & Parallels.